# вывести порядковый номер тега в xml файле

Tags: java, xml

Программа на основе данных из xml файла должна выводить

1. Порядковый номер обрабатываемой фигуры
2. Значение элемента обрабатываемой фигуры
3. Площадь обрабатываемой фигуры.

Не могу реализовать первый пункт.

XML:

```
< shapes >
  < triangle >
  < color > red < /color>
        <side1>1.5</side1 >
  < side2 > 1.5 < /side2>
        <side3>1.5</side3 >
  < /triangle>
    <circle>
        <color>orange</color >
  < diameter > 1.5 < /diameter>
    </circle >
  < square >
  < color > pink < /color>
        <side>4.0</side >
  < /square>
    <rectangle>
        <color>green</color >
  < side1 > 1.5 < /side1>
        <side2>2.5</side2 >
  < /rectangle>
    <circle>
        <color>yellow</color >
  < diameter > 2.5 < /diameter>
    </circle >
  < rectangle >
  < color > red < /color>
        <side1>3.5</side1 >
  < side2 > 2.5 < /side2>
    </rectangle >
  < triangle >
  < color > blue < /color>
        <side1>2.5</side1 >
  < side2 > 2.5 < /side2>
        <side3>2.5</side3 >
  < /triangle>
    <square>
        <color>white</color >
  < side > 3.0 < /side>
    </square >
  < square >
  < color > blue < /color>
        <side>2.0</side >
  < /square>
    <triangle>
        <color>green</color >
  < side1 > 4.0 < /side1>
        <side2>4.0</side2 >
  < side3 > 2.5 < /side3>
    </triangle >

  < /shapes>
```

Class:

```
package sample;

import java.io.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
public class Shapes {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    File fXml = new File("shapes.xml");


    try {
      DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
      DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
      Document doc = db.parse(fXml);

      doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
      System.out.println("Root element [" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName() + "]");

      NodeList nodeLst = doc.getElementsByTagName("circle");
      NodeList nodeLst2 = doc.getElementsByTagName("triangle");
      NodeList nodeLst3 = doc.getElementsByTagName("square");
      NodeList nodeLst4 = doc.getElementsByTagName("rectangle");

      for (int je = 0; je < nodeLst.getLength(); je++) {
        Node fstNode = nodeLst.item(je);
        if (fstNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
          Element elj = (Element) fstNode;
          NodeList nljx = elj.getElementsByTagName("color");
          Element eljx = (Element) nljx.item(0);
          NodeList nljxc = eljx.getChildNodes();
          NodeList nljy = elj.getElementsByTagName("diameter");
          Element eljy = (Element) nljy.item(0);
          NodeList nljyc = eljy.getChildNodes();
          double y = (Double.parseDouble(((Node) nljyc.item(0)).getNodeValue()));
          NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
          System.out.println(
            "krug:" + ((Node) nljxc.item(0)).getNodeValue() + " - " + formatter.format(Math.pow((y / 2), 2) * Math.PI) + ""
          );

        }
      }
      for (int je = 0; je < nodeLst2.getLength(); je++) {
        Node fstNode2 = nodeLst2.item(je);
        if (fstNode2.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
          Element elj = (Element) fstNode2;
          NodeList nljx = elj.getElementsByTagName("color");
          Element eljx = (Element) nljx.item(0);
          NodeList nljxc = eljx.getChildNodes();
          NodeList nljy = elj.getElementsByTagName("side1");
          Element eljy = (Element) nljy.item(0);
          NodeList nljyc = eljy.getChildNodes();
          NodeList nljz = elj.getElementsByTagName("side2");
          Element eljz = (Element) nljz.item(0);
          NodeList nljzc = eljz.getChildNodes();
          NodeList nlje = elj.getElementsByTagName("side3");
          Element elje = (Element) nlje.item(0);
          NodeList nljec = elje.getChildNodes();
          double y = (Double.parseDouble(((Node) nljyc.item(0)).getNodeValue()));
          double z = (Double.parseDouble(((Node) nljzc.item(0)).getNodeValue()));
          double e = (Double.parseDouble(((Node) nljec.item(0)).getNodeValue()));
          double p = (y + z + e) / 2;
          NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");


          System.out.println(
            "treug:" + ((Node) nljxc.item(0)).getNodeValue() + " - " + formatter.format(Math.sqrt(p * (p - y) * (p - z) * (p - e))) + ""
          );

        }
      }
      for (int je = 0; je < nodeLst3.getLength(); je++) {
        Node fstNode3 = nodeLst3.item(je);
        if (fstNode3.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
          Element elj = (Element) fstNode3;
          NodeList nljx = elj.getElementsByTagName("color");
          Element eljx = (Element) nljx.item(0);
          NodeList nljxc = eljx.getChildNodes();
          NodeList nljy = elj.getElementsByTagName("side");
          Element eljy = (Element) nljy.item(0);
          NodeList nljyc = eljy.getChildNodes();
          double y = (Double.parseDouble(((Node) nljyc.item(0)).getNodeValue()));
          NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
          System.out.println(
            "kvadr:" + ((Node) nljxc.item(0)).getNodeValue() + " - " + formatter.format(Math.pow(y, 2)) + ""
          );

        }
      }
      for (int je = 0; je < nodeLst.getLength(); je++) {
        Node fstNode4 = nodeLst4.item(je);
        if (fstNode4.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
          Element elj = (Element) fstNode4;
          NodeList nljx = elj.getElementsByTagName("color");
          Element eljx = (Element) nljx.item(0);
          NodeList nljxc = eljx.getChildNodes();
          NodeList nljy = elj.getElementsByTagName("side1");
          Element eljy = (Element) nljy.item(0);
          NodeList nljyc = eljy.getChildNodes();
          NodeList nljz = elj.getElementsByTagName("side2");
          Element eljz = (Element) nljz.item(0);
          NodeList nljzc = eljz.getChildNodes();
          double y = (Double.parseDouble(((Node) nljyc.item(0)).getNodeValue()));
          double z = (Double.parseDouble(((Node) nljzc.item(0)).getNodeValue()));
          NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
          System.out.println(
            "priam:" + ((Node) nljxc.item(0)).getNodeValue() + " - " + formatter.format(y * z) + ""
          );

        }
      }

    } catch (Exception ei) {}

  }
}
```

Comment: Слишком большое количество дублирующегося кода в java. Обойдите рекурсивно весь документ, проверяйте на подходящий `NodeName` если это фигура, отмечайте это в какой-нибудь переменной, когда будете проходить ее потомков, проверяйте параметры, на каждом уровне будете знать номер элемента в родительском элементе.

Comment: И зачем столько пробелов в XML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для вывода порядкового номера обрабатываемой фигуры нужно воспользоваться одним циклом, вместо трех (тогда номер обрабатываемой фигуры будет номером итерации в цикле). И в зависимости от типа элемента (rectangle, square, circle, triangle ) обрабатывать его соответствующим образом.

Как-то так это можно осуществить:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;

public class Shapes {
    public static final String CIRCLE_SHAPE_NAME = "circle";
    public static final String TRIANGLE_SHAPE_NAME = "triangle";
    public static final String SQUARE_SHAPE_NAME = "square";
    public static final String RECTANGLE_SHAPE_NAME = "rectangle";

    private static String getOneTagByName(Element element, String tagName) {
        return element.getElementsByTagName(tagName).item(0).getTextContent();
    }

    private static String buildOutputShape(String name, String color, Double area, int number) {
        final NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
        return "#" + number + " " + name + ":" + color + " - " + formatter.format(area);
    }

    private static String buildShape(Node node, int number) {
        final Element element = (Element) node;
        final String nodeName = node.getNodeName();
        final String color = getOneTagByName(element, "color");

        final Double area;
        if (CIRCLE_SHAPE_NAME.equals(nodeName)) {
            final String diameterRaw = getOneTagByName(element, "diameter");
            final double radius = Double.valueOf(diameterRaw) / 2;
            area = Math.pow(radius, 2) * Math.PI;
        } else if (TRIANGLE_SHAPE_NAME.equals(nodeName)) {
            final String side1Raw = getOneTagByName(element, "side1");
            final String side2Raw = getOneTagByName(element, "side2");
            final String side3Raw = getOneTagByName(element, "side3");
            final double side1 = Double.valueOf(side1Raw);
            final double side2 = Double.valueOf(side2Raw);
            final double side3 = Double.valueOf(side3Raw);
            final double perimeter = (side1 + side2 + side3) / 2;
            area = Math.sqrt(perimeter * (perimeter - side1) * (perimeter - side2) * (perimeter - side3));
        } else if (SQUARE_SHAPE_NAME.equals(nodeName)) {
            final String sideRaw = getOneTagByName(element, "side");
            final double side = Double.valueOf(sideRaw);
            area = Math.pow(side, 2);
        } else if (RECTANGLE_SHAPE_NAME.equals(nodeName)) {
            final String side1Raw = getOneTagByName(element, "side1");
            final String side2Raw = getOneTagByName(element, "side2");
            final double side1 = Double.valueOf(side1Raw);
            final double side2 = Double.valueOf(side2Raw);
            area = side1 * side2;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unknow shape type. NodeName: " + nodeName);
        }

        return buildOutputShape(nodeName, color, area, number);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final File fXml = new File("shapes.xml");
        try {
            final DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            final DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            final Document doc = db.parse(fXml);
            final NodeList nodesOfShapes = doc.getElementsByTagName("shapes").item(0).getChildNodes();

            final StringBuilder outputBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            int count = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < nodesOfShapes.getLength(); i++) {
                final Node node = nodesOfShapes.item(i);
                if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    final String shapeOutput = buildShape(node, count++);
                    outputBuilder.append(shapeOutput).append('\n');
                }
            }
            System.out.print(outputBuilder.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: разжуйте мне пожалуйста, лучше всего строчкой кода

Comment: как мне запихнуть это всё в один цикл?

Comment: Подредактировал, теперь есть и код.

Comment: от души спасибо, добрый человек, счастья тебе, здоровья, любви, денег, удачи, всего!!!